# global 301 folder redirect with conditions and space (%20) in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have an old folder structure as follows

```
http://www.example.com/2014_Files/.../...
http://www.example.com/2012 files/.../...
http://www.example.com/2013 Files/.../...
http://www.example.com/All 2009 Files/.../...
```

- that I would like to redirect to:

  http://www.example.com/archives/old-files/2005_Pages/.../...
  http://www.example.com/archives/old-files/2012 files/.../...
  http://www.example.com/archives/old-files/2013 Files/.../...
  http://www.example.com/archives/old-files/All 2009 Files/.../...

the list contains 16 folders, *RewriteCond* would do it however, I have the following redirects as exception from the general rule above:

```
Redirect 301 "/2013 Files/Gallery D Dest/index.htm"             http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2014_Files/Fest_4_Dest_/index.htm"               http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2014_Files/AssrtDEST/index.htm"                  http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2013 Files/Gallery B Dest/"                      http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2014_Files/RPen_A _dest/index.htm"               http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2014_Files/NewFest_Sub/index.htm"                http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2013 Files/Gallery E/Gallery E dest/index.htm"   http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2014_Files/Dest_B_dest/index.htm"                http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2013 Files/Bob_Gallery_2_Dest/index.htm"         http://www.example.com/different_location
Redirect 301 "/2013 Files/Gallery FDest/index_2.htm"            http://www.example.com/different_location
```

I was unable to build a working rule-set, one issue is the blank spaces in the old URL structure, that I was able to partially fix with with using quotes but I wasn't able to efficiently include the exceptions, getting 500 Errors. Any help is greatly appreciated! **Thank you!**

Comment: For 500 error check your error.log and provide the exact error text you see there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use "\s" instead of spaces in the left part of the redirect rule, while using "\ " on the right part. So the rules should look like this:

```
RewriteRule  ^All\s2009\sfiles/(.*)  /archives/old-website/All\ 2009\ Files/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the complete, working .htaccess file, flawless!